# Many-to-Many - get threads of a user

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am coding a private message system and I've got an issue where I am unable to get correctly the list of threads of a user.

I've got 3 entities :

- User
- Thread
- Post

The Thread Entity has many to many relationship :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $users;
```

I have got one query working to achieve something close to what I want :

```
public function getThreads($user) {
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->leftJoin('t.users', 'u')
                    ->addSelect('u')
                ->where('u.id = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user)
                ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
                ->setMaxResults(20);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I get **my** name in the list of threads:

```
 From     | Text           | date   
----------|----------------|--------
 Hotgeart | Hello :)       | 31 jan 
 Hotgeart | Wanna go out?  | 20 jan 
 Hotgeart | I love book    | 10 jan
```

And obviously I want to get the name of the other user of the tread not my :

```
 From     | Text           | date   
----------|----------------|--------
 Homer    | Hello :)       | 31 jan 
 Bart     | Wanna go out?  | 20 jan 
 Lisa     | I love book    | 10 jan
```

What do I need to change in my query to get the correct result above?

P.S: It can be a DQL query.

**Edit complete entities:**

- [Thread.php](http://pastie.org/private/ulinqxhptiww8puzayikpq)
- [Post.php](http://pastie.org/private/e2uhoyvddyavmjt0oeyaq)

### I'm close

**Edit 3 feb:**

I've something close what I want :

```
public function getThreads($user) {
   $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
                $q->leftJoin('t.users', 'u', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, $q->expr()->eq('u.id', ':user'))
                ->leftJoin('t.users', 'u2', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, $q->expr()->neq('u2.id', ':user'))
                    ->addSelect('partial u2.{xxx, xxx, ...}')
                ->where('u.id = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user)
                ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
                ->setMaxResults(20);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

It's give me this table :

```
 From     | Text           | date   
----------|----------------|--------
 NULL     | Hello :)       | 31 jan 
 Homer    | Hello :)       | 31 jan 
 NULL     | Wanna go out?  | 20 jan 
 Bart     | Wanna go out?  | 20 jan 
 NULL     | I love book    | 10 jan 
 Lisa     | I love book    | 10 jan
```

If I had an `->addSelect('partial u2.{xxx, xxx, ...}')` to the first *JOIN* I've the same table but *NULL* are replace by hotgeart (me).

Comment: Hey Hotgeart, I would like to see all your Entity class definitions, so I can understand the problem better. Can you put the definitions in a Pastie?

Comment: I edited, in my user.php there's no mention of thread or post.

Comment: Which user or users should appear in 'From' column? The one who starts the thread, last one how send post to the thread or all of participients of the thread?

Comment: There is always 2 users in a conversation. And when a user want to get his list of conversations, this sould display the name of the other user.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getThreads($user) {
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.users', 'u')
                ->addSelect('u')
            ->where('u.id = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)//limits result to user $user
            ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(20);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

You will have to replace that in favor of IN/EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your `Post` mapping to User as a ManyToOne:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 private $user;
```

And your query will look like:

```
public function getThreads($user) {
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->leftJoin('t.posts', 'p')
                ->leftJoin('p.user', 'u')
                ->addSelect('t')
                ->where('u.id = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user)
                ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
                ->setMaxResults(20);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

In this way, you'll have just thread entities. You will not get the user directly from the Thread entity, BTW, because you will not know in advance which posts from that thread are authored by him.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the Threads in the next way:

```
public function getThreads($user) {
    $em     = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query  = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT     t
         FROM       AcmeMessageBundle:Thread t
         WHERE      :user MEMBER OF t.users
         ORDER BY   t.date DESC'
    )
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->setMaxResults( 20 );

    $threads  = $query->getResult();

    return $threads;
}
```

And you will receive a Doctrine ArrayCollection of Threads (you need to remove AcmeMessageBundle and put the right name of your Bundle).

**EDIT:**
Reading your question again, and seeing your examples, I think that what you want are not the threads, are the posts of the threads related with the user. You could do this adding a bidirectional relation between your Post and your Thread entities, as below:

In the Thread entity, add this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\MessageBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="thread")
 */
private $posts;
```

And in the *construct* function:

```
$this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

In the Post entity, modify your lines as here:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread", inversedby="posts")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $thread;
```

And generate the getter and setter for the posts in the Thread entity, so in this way, you can get the posts after you get the threads as above.

Comment: Same result, but behind symfony make for each thread a query for get the user (me not the other). You can see the queries here : http://pastie.org/private/rtykno0v1140ve0ktsk5q . There's no way to keep my query and say to sql to join to the other user? Or the logic of my private message system is bad? That's the good way to do it, no ?

Comment: No, post is useless to get threads informations, all informations is in table *thread* and *thread_user*. I've a text cache and date cache in the entity thread and the users is in thread_user create by doctrine. So I've already the informations of the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some design issue here.

As per my understanding, a thread is a discussion, started by a user. A post is individual message in the thread.

If you can explain how you are planning on things to work, it would be easier to say how your entities should be associated. As far as I understand your problem,

if the messaging happens between only 2 people, you dont need many-to-many relation. You would just need, sender and receiver properties with ManyToOne association to `User` in `Thread` entity. Your `Post` entity looks good. After that back to your peoblem,

get the list of the threads by a user:

```
 $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('s.username', 't.message', 't.date') // assuming the fields
            ->join('t.sender', 's')
            ->join('t.receiver', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(20);

return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: With your query, i've only 50% of my threads. I get only threads where I'm the receiver. What about threads where I'm the sender ? I need a *OR*. And *OR* take too many ressource. I've already a MP system and it's like that. That's why I recode it. My design is code, juste need the good query.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the people involved in a `thread`, you have to refine a bit your query. Currently, you're filtering by user `id` to get those threads in which a user is in. However, that doesn't get you the other users that are in that thread (expected behaviour) hence the problem.

What you have to do is:

1. First, find out the threads in which a user is in.
2. Two, retrieve those threads with all the users involved in them.

This can be mixed in a single query:

```
$em = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();// Entity manager, I'm using SF and querying in a controller for a simplicity. You can adapt it to a Repository if you like.

$dql = $em
        ->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:Thread")// Change this to suit you
        ->createQueryBuilder('t2')
        ->select('t2.id')
        ->leftJoin('t2.users', 'u2')
        ->where('u2.id = :user')
        ->getDQL();// Subquery that will retrieve those threads in which user with id = $user is involved.

$qb = $em
        ->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:Thread")// Change this to suit you
        ->createQueryBuilder('t');// Querybuilder object: useful for the 'in' part of the query.

$q2 = $qb
        ->addSelect('u')
        ->leftJoin('t.users', 'u')
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('t.id', $dql))
        ->setParameter('user', 1)// I force 1 for simplicity, you can use a variable.
        ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(20)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();// Retrieve threads in which user is in. Each thread will have in users those users involved in the thread.
```

This query will have as a result an array of threads in which `user` is in. Each of those threads will have in the `users` variable the list of users that took part in the thread. `user` will be in those `users` variables. You can filter it in the query if you like adding `->where('u.id <> :user')` for instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same result than my *Edit 3 feb*. Duplicate row.

Comment: here it's not repeating anything and am using your code for the entities. Can you be more specific?